# Having trouble downloading and displaying inputstream in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to grab an inputStream from a secure website, convert it to a bitmap, and display it. The way I have my code set up (with the Logs displaying length of the byte array etc.) right now is because my error is

01-25 10:29:44.857: D/skia(13452): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

However that byte array length check responds:

01-25 10:29:44.834: W/bytes length(13452): 21844

I think this must mean that my byte array isn't being downloaded correctly, but I can't figure out how to check that/how I would fix it anyways.

I included my defaultHttpClient code because I want to make sure the way I'm dealing with security isn't somehow affecting the data.

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://my.patlive.com//mailbox/messages/get.aspx?MsgID=" + messageId + "&format=bmp");

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();

o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

InputStream is = httpclient.execute(post).getEntity().getContent();
byte[] bytes = readFully(is);

Log.w("bytes length", "" + bytes.length);

bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```

Thanks in advance, this has been stumping me for a few days.

Comment: Have you at least debugged your code????

Comment: try this in an asynctask.

Comment: @Daniel Unless I badly misunderstand, the fact that my byte array is filled at all should be enough to turn it into a bitmap, albeit a badly malformed one if the data is wrong. I feel like the "ImageDecoder::Factory returned null" error speaks to a different problem with the file itself or the way I'm trying to convert it.

Comment: @DhruvGairola It is in an asynctask, I was just saving code by not showing the wrapper. All this is in a try/catch inside the doInBackground method of an asynctask